# NameError : name [...] is not defined whithin a class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm facing an error while trying to use an entry widget in tkinter (need to get player's names for a TicTacToe)
I've created a class Player :

```
class Player:
""" Informations sur les joueurs """
def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.score = 0
    self.active = 0

def get_name(self, main_window):

    name_selection_window = Toplevel()
    name_selection_window.resizable(0,0)
    name_selection_window.wait_visibility()
    name_selection_window.grab_set()
    name_selection_window.transient(main_window)
    name_selection_window.focus_force()

    player_name_label = Label(name_selection_window, text="Nom du Joueur 1 : ")
    player_name_label.pack()    

    name_entry = Entry(name_selection_window, bd=3)
    name_entry.bind("<Return>",self.entry_master)
    name_entry.pack()

    main_window.wait_window(name_selection_window)

def entry_master(self, event):
    """Récupère l'entrée pour chaque joueur."""    
    name = name_entry.get()
    if name != "":
        self.name = name
    name_selection_window.destroy()
    pass
```

(I can't get correct paddings within this editor I don't know why, sorry for this)
Every other parts of the code work, and when I launch it, a window pop up and ask to type a name. But when I press ENTER to validate the entry

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\miniconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "N:\ISN\tictactoe\jeu_v2.py", line 32, in entry_master
    name = name_entry.get()
NameError: name 'name_entry' is not defined
```

I don't understand why, as name_entry is defined in get_name(). It works when I use both get_name and entry_master outside a class.

Can you help me to resolve this ? Thanks

Comment: ...because it isn't? You're missing some `self`.

Comment: why isnt `name_entry` a self variable  in `get_name`?

Comment: Because you didn't write  `self.name_entry` -- Python doesn't assume that local variables in methods are instance properties that way that some other languages you might be familiar with do.  To set an instance property in an instance method, you need `self`:  `self.foo = ...`.  To retrieve it you still need self:  `foo = self.foo`

Comment: Thanks for your help ! After adding self. before each variable needed, everything works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is big on explicitly stating where a variable goes. You likely want to have `name_entry` as an instance variable. To do so, replace all instances of `name_entry` with `self.name_entry`. `self` refers to the current object, and you want to save that object there. Otherwise, it's just a local variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, problem is solved now ;)

Comment: @ThibaultJ Glad to hear! Remember to mark an answer as correct if it solved the problem.

Comment: @ThibaultJ There's a checkmark next to an answer to mark that answer as correct and the question as solved.